# Why can't I edit the call log for an unsaved incoming number?

Tags: java, android

I want to edit a call log history. I wrote simple code for editing the call log. I put `CACHED_NAME` or other name variables, but I didn't see any changes in the call log. Why doesn't it work? Here is my code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "Edited Name");
getContentResolver().update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
values, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(number) });
```

Edit: I added write and read call log permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: Are you requesting permission on runtime as well or just in manifest?

Comment: yes, i am asking for permission for write call logs.

Answer (score 1):

Because the system doesn't want random apps to be able to update the call log with possibly incorrect data.  So they don't export that capability to just any app-  you have to be the registered telecom app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have no idea to do this. I searched on google 5-10 mins but still no explonation. Have you any sources or would you like to tell me some simply explonation?

Comment: [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html) is what Gabe is talking about